# Comparison operation being completely ignored

Tags: c, if-statement, comparison

I am trying to write a test program for a library I am making.  This test program is supposed to test every possible value that goes into some functions.  Here is the code:

```
void test_int8_smr()
{
    for (int i = INT8_MIN; i <= INT8_MAX; i++)
    {
        int8_t testval = i;
        int8_t result = from_int8_smr(to_int8_smr(testval));

        if (testval != result)
        {
            if (testval == 0x80) // This if statement gets ignored.
            {
                continue;
            }
            printf("test_int8_smr()     failed: testval = 0x%02hhX, result = 0x%02hhX\n", testval, result);
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("test_int8_smr()     succeeded for all possible values. \n");
}
```

Here is the output:

> test_int8_smr()     failed: testval = 0x80, result = 0x00

This if statement appears to be ignored:

```
            if (testval == 0x80)
            {
                continue;
            }
```

This is very baffling.  Any idea why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: I think the compiler is optimizing the code and since you are not doing anything in there it ignores it. Could you put a `printf` and see what happens?

Comment: @user3121023: It's not clear from OP's code whether that would be the wrong or the right behavior.

Answer (score 4):

`testval` has type `int8_t` so its range of possible values is `-0x80` to `0x7f`. It can never be equal to `0x80` and thus the equality relation is always false and subject to constant folding and dead code removal.